# haskell-vim-now fail to install in nixos

Tags: haskell, vim, nixos

nixos 17.09

Installing haskell-vim-now as suggested [here](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now/blob/master/README.md)

> bash <(curl -sL https://git.io/haskell-vim-now) --nix

Output puzzles me:

```
--- Creating vim config symlinks
        ~/.vimrc -> /home/tort/.config/haskell-vim-now/.vimrc
        ~/.vim   -> /home/tort/.config/haskell-vim-now/.vim
--- Installing plugins using vim-plug... 
HvnArgs {hvnArgsNoHoogleDb = False, hvnArgsNoHelperBinaries = False}
 Setting up GHC if needed... 
/bin/sh: stack: command not found 
Stack setup failed with error 127
*** setup_haskell.hs failed with error 1.
*** Aborting...
```

Why script doesn't see stack?

```
[host@host:~]$ which stack
/home/tort/.nix-profile/bin/stack

[host@host:~]$ nix-env -q '.*stack.*'
stack-1.5.1
stack2nix-0.1.3.0
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You run the install script with `bash` but the install script seems to use `sh` which probably doesn't know where to look for `stack`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of installing haskell-vim-now in nixos works for me:

```
bash <(curl -sL https://git.io/haskell-vim-now) --basic
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
stack install codex hscope ghc-mod hasktags hoogle --nix
```